# If statement for if a variable I'm searching for doesn't exist?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I currently have a function that accepts a parameter `P_Item_Code` of type `varchar2`.

And I'm wondering if there's 
an `If does not exist` statement where I can
return a string

`Item Code does not exist` ?

Idea below being similar to what I'm thinking of :

```
(P_Binder Number number, P_Item_Code varchar2)
 If P_item_code not exists THEN
 R_Output := 'Item code does not exist'
 Return R_Output;
```

Comment: [`Not Exist`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php)?

Comment: what if exists..?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is just using a `count()`.

To do so, declare this variable:

```
record_count number;
```

Then use it in your function's body, like so:

```
select count(*) into record_count
from some_code_table
where item_code_key = P_item_code;

if record_count=0 then
  R_Output := 'Item code does not exist';
  Return R_Output;
end if;
```

Just replace the identifiers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if a non null value exists for `P_Item_Code` or not.
You may check if the variable is null and also augment it by adding a `DEFAULT NULL` for cases where the argument is not passed at all.

```
(P_Binder Number, P_Item_Code varchar2 DEFAULT NULL) --If the calling program doesn't pass anything it will be null
 If P_item_code IS NULL THEN
   R_Output := 'Item code does not exist'
 Return R_Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Directly bind by using `nvl()` function as :

```
R_Output := nvl(to_char(P_Binder) ,'Item code does not exist');
```